# New environment error

Tags: environments, environment-variables, quotation

### Edit

As David rightly pointed out in the comment, I did not post what I intended. The desired output is a [pull quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_quote), that is a quote positioned on the right-hand or left-hand side of the page, wrapped by the main text, with the desired colored background declared by `colorquote`.

——————————————————————————————————————————

I’ve just started to learn how new environments work, so please bear with me.

I have tried the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{Archivo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

%%%%This is the environment I’m trying to create%%%%
\definecolor{colorquote}{HTML}{e8e9f5}
\newtcolorbox{myquote}{colback=colorquote, colframe=colorquote}
\newenvironment{pullquote}[1]
    \begin{wrapfigure}{#1}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{myquote}
        \end{myquote}
    \end{wrapfigure}


\author{}
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    \section{This is some section title}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{pullquote}{R}
        Here is a quotation
    \end{pullquote}
    \lipsum[3]
    
\end{document}
```

Even when I try on one line:

```
\newenvironment{pullquote}[1]{\begin{wrapfigure}{#1}{0.4\textwidth}\begin{myquote}\end{myquote}\end{wrapfigure}}
```

The new environment just won’t work, and I cannot figure out why. What is wrong with it?

Also, I need the variable, but I’m not sure that I’m using it correctly. The variable would be used to either put the quoted text on the right-hand side or the left-hand side.

Comment: So the simple package `tcolorbox` overrides the entire LaTeX document regarding environment declaration?

Comment: What are these specific declaration? Because I can’t seem to find them.

Comment: I am using `tcolorbox`... it’s how I can create a background color for the quote..

Comment: I’m sorry, I’m missing vocabulary here. I don’t understand what you mean. What’s the (broken) outer definition? And what is the form that appears in the document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error from the posted code is

```
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode.
l.20     \begin{wrapfigure}{#
                             1}{0.4\textwidth}
?
```

as

```
\newenvironment{pullquote}[1]
    \begin{wrapfigure}{#1}{0.4\textwidth}
```

is

```
\newenvironment{pullquote}[1]
   {\begin}
   {wrapfigure}
   {#1}{0.4\textwidth}
```

which defines the `pullquote` environment to have begin code `\begin` and end code `wrapfigure`. That is not intended but not an error. But then the remaning tokens leave `#1` not inside a definition, so you get the error.

Changing things to

```
\newenvironment{pullquote}[1]
    {\begin{wrapfigure}{#1}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{myquote}}
        {\end{myquote}
    \end{wrapfigure}}
```

runs without error and produces

[image]

Which may or may not be what you want (you did not say what output you wanted)

Or

[image]

from

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{Archivo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

%%%%This is the environment I’m trying to create%%%%
\definecolor{colorquote}{HTML}{e8e9f5}
\newtcolorbox{myquote}{colback=colorquote, colframe=colorquote}
\newenvironment{pullquote}[1]
    {\begin{wrapfigure}{#1}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{myquote}}
        {\end{myquote}
    \end{wrapfigure}}


\author{}
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    \section{This is some section title}
    
    \lipsum[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{myquote}
        Here is a quotation
    \end{myquote}
\end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum*[3]
    
\end{document}
```

Note that you can not "hide" a tcolorbox definition inside a standard `\newenvironment` which is why there is the `\newtcolorbox` declaration form.

Comment: Ok thank you for this, I think I get it now, though it is indeed not the output I want. The output desired is a [pull quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_quote) that is on the right-hand or left-hand side of the page, wrapped by the main text, with the background color.

Comment: @Louis.vgn that's the other issue about not using tcolorbox inside a newenviornment form.

Comment: OK thank you. Then, the `newenvironment{pullquote}` is simply useless, since it is unusable due to the `tcolorbox` used inside the very `newenvironment`?

Comment: Alright, now I see what was wrong with my answer: someone changed `lipsum`...